# LINQ script class throwing TaskCanceledException Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on .NET CORE 6 application along with Entity Framework CORE 7. I have class where I have written LINQ script. This is async method. I am not sure why I am getting `TaskCanceledException` error here...

[image]

`linq`

```
public override async Task<(int, JobProfile)> Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            var query1 = await (from x in db.JobProfiles
                          where x.JobProfileId == JobProfileId
                          select x).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return (0, query1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

`calling above method`

```
 var queryResult = await _getJobQuery.Execute();
```

Comment: `TaskCanceledException` is common sign of timeouts, though I don't recall seeing it as is thrown by ORMs.

Comment: Also is there any particular reason to use EF 7 with .NET 6?

Comment: with EF should I use with .NET CORE 6?

Comment: Do you get this exception only when you run the program with the debugger attached, or you get it also when you run it with Ctrl+F5?

Comment: I believe is when Ctrl+F5